# Xcode - No such File or Directory

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with the Google Maps Framework, but when I finish my app,I no longer need this framework. I delete the framework and #import, but when I build the app, I have an error:

```
error: /Users/***/Desktop/App/3 - Buzz/APPs/iOS/Template/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle: No such file or directory
```

I deleting the folder, but I can't find the solution. Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Dont understand... you delete framework and you dont know why bulid error "no such file" exist???

Comment: Look into `Build Phases` if there are still any references to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Add your sdk location to Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you can not find the framework. You have to import it in this section.
[image]

Comment: I think so too. I do not have other alternatives